# Is it possible to use SSL client certificate authentication with client programs that do not specifically accommodate them?

Tags: linux, ssl, http, ssl-certificate, client-certificate

I have set up a webserver with several self-hosted apps for my personal use. In order to make sure that I am the only person who can connect to my server, I have generated client authentication certificates on my server and transferred them to my local computer. There, I installed the .pfx certificate I downloaded into Firefox and Chrome. On the server, side, I configured nginx with `ssl_verify_client on;`.

For the purely browser-based webapps, this is working great. However some of my apps have desktop clients, and they do not have a means of adding certificates.

Is there some way to install a client authentication certificate system-wide in Linux?

I was thinking maybe it would be possible to somehow insert the client certificate into https requests outgoing from my PC to my server's IP, might that work, and how would I do that?

Comment: You can't alter HTTPS (more generally SSL/TLS) outside the endpoints -- that's the whole point of a secure protocol -- except with a (visible) interceptor which acts like the server to the (real) client and like the client to the (real) server; IF an app uses the system truststore you can add your own CA/root cert for the interceptor to that system truststore, otherwise this probably doesn't work. For _Java_ apps IF they use the default `SSLSocketFactory`, or middleware like `URLConnection` which does so, you can give that `javax.net.ssl.keyStore*` sysprops to do client auth per the doc.

Comment: Is it possible to set up some sort of virtual proxy type thing on my local machine which 
 decrypts, adds the required header to everything before re-encrypting and passing to the ultimate destination?

Comment: Yes, there are proxies that can accept an incoming http or https connection, and make their own https connection with a client certificate to your server. This is also called "man-in-the-middle attack", so using this to make something *more secure* is a somewhat interesting idea. Depending on what the apps do in detail (you didn't tell us), it might work, or not.

Comment: @dirkt the desktop apps sync to a host via http. Unfortunately some of the desktop apps do not have a way to include client certificates. I was thinking that a proxy could be used to add the client certificate into the headers of all http requests.

Comment: Yes, I understood what you want to do. And that will work in the sense of "now the desktop apps can connect to the server". It may not necessarily work in the sense of "now everything is more secure", because https is really built to ensure end-to-end validation, and you are breaking this principle by using a proxy. And "the desktop apps sync to a host" is too vague to say anything. You'd have to look closely at what they are doing. Which cannot be done in a Q&A.

Comment: If I understand correctly, this does what I want. I'd be curious to hear from anyone who has actually used it: https://github.com/ghostunnel/ghostunnel